# Не работает фильтр DataFrame по дате

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, анализ-данных

Мне нужно отфильтровать `dataframe` по диапазону дат, введенному в графическом интерфейсе.

При попытке реализовать это через метод `dataframe.loc` я получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'

Гугл показывает только варианты ошибки между 'int' и 'str' \ 'timestamp' и 'str'

Переменные `BeginLogDate` и `EndLogDate` относятся к типу `string` формата `'yyyy-MM-dd'`

Что тут реализовано не так?

```py
# Чтение файла с преобразованием в массив Pandas
dt = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=r'{}'.format(input_file),
                 sep=separator,
                 header=0,
                 index_col=['Index'],
                 names=['Index', 'Type', 'Date/Time', 'Unit', 'Scenario',
                        'Sensor Type', 'Limit', 'Axes', 'DSP', 'Limit Type',
                        'Limit Value', 'Max', 'HP (Hz)', 'LP (Hz)', 'Alarm', 'Stop'],
                 parse_dates=['Date/Time'],
                 na_values='---',
                 encoding=encoding
                 )

# По умолчанию, датчик записывает моменты обрыва и включения питания. В этих строках нет полезной информации.
# Удаление строк, в которых Limit Value = None (Включение и выключение системы)
dt = dt.dropna(subset=['Limit Value'])

# Фильтр значений по диапазону дат, введенному в gui
begin = pd.to_datetime(BeginLogDate+' '+'00:00:00')
end = pd.to_datetime(EndLogDate+' '+'23:59:59')
dt = dt.loc[begin:end]
```

Comment: попробуйте `dt = dt[dt['Date/Time'].between(begin,end)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.loc[slice]` - фильтрует записи по значениям индекса, которые у вас, судя по ошибке, целые значения. Поэтому вы получаете ошибку `'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'`.

Отфильтровать данные можно так:

```
res = df.query("@begin <= `Date/Time` <= @end")
```

Пример:

```
In [196]: df
Out[196]:
   Date/Time
0 2022-01-01
1 2022-01-20
2 2021-10-10

In [197]: BeginLogDate = "2022-01-01"
     ...: EndLogDate = "2022-01-20"
     ...:
     ...: begin = pd.to_datetime(BeginLogDate)
     ...: end = pd.to_datetime(EndLogDate) + pd.offsets.Day(1) - pd.offsets.Micro(1)
     ...:
     ...: res = df.query("@begin <= `Date/Time` <= @end")

In [198]: res
Out[198]:
   Date/Time
0 2022-01-01
1 2022-01-20
```

---

PS [вариант предложенный @SergFSM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373296/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-dataframe-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5/1373302#comment2438785_1373296) тоже правильно отрабатывает:

```
In [199]: df[df['Date/Time'].between(begin, end)]
Out[199]:
   Date/Time
0 2022-01-01
1 2022-01-20
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы натолкнули меня на решение проблемы. Явное указание индекса, по которому требуется отфильтровать и явное определение неравенства помогло. `dt = dt.loc[(dt['Date/Time'] >= begin) & (dt['Date/Time'] <= end)]`

Answer (score 0):

Знак конкатенации (BeginLogDate+' '+'00:00:00') наверное должно быть

```
(BeginLogDate + ' ' + '00:00:00')
```

Comment: а чем этот код отличается от кода в вопросе?